# Refresh data in custom adapter created for AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, arraylist, autocompletetextview

I created custom adapter by extending BaseAdapter and implementing Filterable interface. This adapter is used for suggest phone number to user when they type a contact number or contact person name.`ArrayList<String> data` contain those data with the pattern of "person name:number" which are extracted from phone.

It's working find except for one issue. If I search for contacts start with letter "A" it's show the data correctly. If I delete that and type "B" again it shows both contacts start with "A" and "B". I know that I have to clear  `ArrayList<String> matchedResults`(Check the code) in some method before add new data but when I did that It gave me an empty ArrayList. In which method at which point I should do that or is there a different solution for this ?

here's the code

```
public class AutoCompleteAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> data;
private ArrayList<String> matchedResults = new ArrayList<String>();

public AutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> namesAndNumbers) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = namesAndNumbers;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return matchedResults.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return matchedResults.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, parent, false);

    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView numberTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.number);

    String[] split = matchedResults.get(position).split(":");

    nameTextView.setText(split[0]);
    numberTextView.setText(split[1]);

    return view;
}


@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if(constraint != null || constraint.length() != 0) {

                for (String loop:data) {

                    int charSequenceSize = constraint.length();

                    if(onlyText(constraint.toString()) && !matchedResults.contains(loop)){
                        String[] split = loop.split(":");
                        String substring = split[0].substring(0, charSequenceSize);
                        if (substring.equalsIgnoreCase(constraint.toString())){
                            matchedResults.add(loop);
                        }
                    }else if(onlyNumbers(constraint.toString())){
                        String[] split = loop.split(":");
                        String substring = split[1].substring(0, charSequenceSize);
                        if (substring.equals(constraint.toString()) && !matchedResults.contains(loop) ){
                            matchedResults.add(loop);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            results.values = matchedResults;
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            results.values = matchedResults;
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    };
}

public boolean onlyText(String text) {

    boolean result = false;

    if (Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z ]+", text) && text.length() >= 1) {

        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}

public boolean onlyNumbers(String text) {

    boolean result = false;

    if (Pattern.matches("[0-9+]+", text) && text.length() >= 1) {

        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: use a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, and setup its `FilterQueryProvider`, why do you use a `BaseAdapter` when dealing with cursor based data model?

Answer (score 0):

update your filter to this

```
  @Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return nameFilter;
}

Filter nameFilter = new Filter() {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (constraint != null) {
            matchedResults.clear();
            for (String item : data) {
                if (item.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    matchedResults.add(item);
                }
            }
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = matchedResults;
            filterResults.count = matchedResults.size();
            return filterResults;
        } else {
            return new FilterResults();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        ArrayList<String> filteredList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
            data.clear();
            for (String c : filteredList) {
                data.add(c);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};
```

So your entire code it be like this :

```
public class AutoCompleteAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> data;
private ArrayList<String> matchedResults = new ArrayList<String>();

public AutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> namesAndNumbers) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = namesAndNumbers;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return matchedResults.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return matchedResults.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, parent, false);

    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView numberTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.number);

    String[] split = matchedResults.get(position).split(":");

    nameTextView.setText(split[0]);
    numberTextView.setText(split[1]);

    return view;
}


@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return nameFilter;
}

Filter nameFilter = new Filter() {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (constraint != null) {
            matchedResults.clear();
            for (String item : data) {
                if (item.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    matchedResults.add(item);
                }
            }
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = matchedResults;
            filterResults.count = matchedResults.size();
            return filterResults;
        } else {
            return new FilterResults();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        ArrayList<String> filteredList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
            data.clear();
            for (String c : filteredList) {
                data.add(c);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};

public boolean onlyText(String text) {

    boolean result = false;

    if (Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z ]+", text) && text.length() >= 1) {

        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}

public boolean onlyNumbers(String text) {

    boolean result = false;

    if (Pattern.matches("[0-9+]+", text) && text.length() >= 1) {

        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

I hope to be helpful for you .

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work. it remove all the data form  data Array List except the one I searched. when i try to search for second time for different data set starts with different letter, data Array List  don't have that information.

Comment: i try this code with ArrayAdapter and it's work . try to use in **publishResults** `matchedResults.clear()` and `matchedResults.add` instead of **data**